# how to create triadic relations in laravel framework

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I need to create triadic relation in laravel framework.

Consider three models:
Card, Notes, User.

Card is related to notes and user, while they are related to each other.
Now in models, when the relation ship would be drafted, 
Card->belongTo -> Notes
Notes-> hasMany -> Card

The problem is when 
relationship between card and user is created, keeping to above rules,the connection is not made.

user -> hasMany ->card;
Card ->belongTo -> user.

stacktrace:

```
1/1 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

    in RouteCollection.php line 218
    at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
    at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
    at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
    at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
    at require_once('/home/sayali/people_finder/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

my user.php - has a func Cards

```
public function cards()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
}
```

in cards.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: While I don't really understand why you would want a 2-way relationship, you're basically overwriting the same change. First you give a User some Cards and then you say those Cards have a User. That's the same thing, isn't it?

Comment: that is the question part, I m assigning many users Card, but after that if I try to access user from a particular Card, Its throwing MethodNotAllowedHttpException .

Comment: You are assigning many cards to a user and 1 user to a card. That's really somthing else. Can you paste your stacktrace? There is probably something wrong with your routes.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @Loek no that is not my problem, I have not used patch request, its a post request itself. There is some issue in the way relationship is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stacktrace, you're not submitting information in a POST request or you route isn't responding on POST requests. [Check this thread on the Laravel forums for some more explanation.](https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/general-discussion/methodnotallowedhttpexception)

Basically make sure your form submit method and route response method are the same thing.

I'm still not a huge proponent of your triadic relation though. I'd give every card a user OR give a user all his cards and then work from there. 2-way relations are bound to get messed up in my experience.